# Access to all Native Views on ReactNative

Tags: java, android, react-native

I need to access to all the UiComponent NativeViews in android, in ios i was able with the following code but on Android I'm not able to get the "ViewRegistry".

```
[self.bridge.uiManager addUIBlock:^(__unused RCTUIManager *uiManager, NSDictionary<NSNumber *, UIView *> *viewRegistry) {

    for (NSNumber *viewIndex in [viewRegistry allKeys]) {
        if(viewIndex != reactTag){
            if ([viewRegistry[viewIndex] isKindOfClass:[CDTRNJWPlayerView class]]) {
                CDTRNJWPlayerView *JWPlayerView = (CDTRNJWPlayerView*) viewRegistry[viewIndex];
                [JWPlayerView JWPlayerPause];
            }
        }
    }

}];
```

Here what I've in the android module, as you can see I'm able just to get the current istance with the resolveViewManager method, I'm not able to do the same as I've done in Obj-c

```
UIManagerModule uiManager = mReactContext.getNativeModule(UIManagerModule.class);

    uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock() {
        public void execute (NativeViewHierarchyManager nvhm) {

            CDTRNJWPlayerComponent jwplayerComponent = (CDTRNJWPlayerComponent) nvhm.resolveView(reactTag);
            CDTRNJWPlayerManager jwplayerManager = (CDTRNJWPlayerManager) nvhm.resolveViewManager(reactTag);
            JWPlayerView jwplayerView = (JWPlayerView) jwplayerComponent.getChildAt(0);
            jwplayerManager.pause(jwplayerView);

        }
    });
```

Comment: were you able to solve it?